# Adsense return the wrong selectors on my AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I'm using AMP auto-ads and I'm not seeing any ads. 
When checking the console, I found this:

> log.js:251 [amp-auto-ads] No anchor element found

I dug a bit and found out that placements come from a remote config from Adsense:

```
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/getconfig/ama?client=ca-pub-7726580065556509&plah=[site_url]&ama_t=amp&url=[Page_url]&__amp_source_origin=[site_url]
```

I get the following config:

```
{
   "producerVersion":"20200506_020425",
   "placements":[
      {
         "anchor":{
            "selector":"ARTICLE",
            "index":0,
            "sub":{
               "selector":"P",
               "all":true,
               "min_c":100
            }
         },
         "pos":4,
         "type":1,
         "style":{
            "top_m":10,
            "bot_m":24
         }
      },
      {
         "anchor":{
            "selector":"ARTICLE",
            "index":1,
            "sub":{
               "selector":"P",
               "all":true,
               "min_c":100
            }
         },
         "pos":4,
         "type":1,
         "style":{
            "top_m":10,
            "bot_m":24
         }
      },
      {
         "anchor":{
            "selector":"ARTICLE",
            "index":2,
            "sub":{
               "selector":"P",
               "all":true,
               "min_c":100
            }
         },
         "pos":4,
         "type":1,
         "style":{
            "top_m":10,
            "bot_m":24
         }
      },
      {
         "anchor":{
            "selector":"ARTICLE.post",
            "index":0,
            "sub":{
               "selector":"P",
               "all":true,
               "min_c":100
            }
         },
         "pos":1,
         "type":1,
         "style":{
            "top_m":10,
            "bot_m":24
         }
      },
      {
         "anchor":{
            "selector":"ARTICLE",
            "index":0,
            "sub":{
               "selector":"P",
               "all":true,
               "min_c":100
            }
         },
         "pos":1,
         "type":1,
         "style":{
            "top_m":10,
            "bot_m":24
         }
      },
      {
         "anchor":{
            "selector":"ARTICLE.post",
            "index":0,
            "sub":{
               "selector":"P",
               "all":true,
               "min_c":100
            }
         },
         "pos":4,
         "type":1,
         "style":{
            "top_m":10,
            "bot_m":24
         }
      }
   ],
   "attributes":{
      "data-tag-origin":"ampa",
      "data-package":"7979106250"
   },
   "optInStatus":[
      1
   ],
   "adConstraints":{
      "initialMinSpacing":"1vp",
      "subsequentMinSpacing":[
         {
            "adCount":3,
            "spacing":"2vp"
         },
         {
            "adCount":6,
            "spacing":"3vp"
         }
      ],
      "maxAdCount":8
   }
}
```

The problem is that I have no `ARTICLE` tag on my HTML page. 
This is why I don't see any AMP ads. 
Is this something on Adsense to fix or for me to deal with and change my HTML structure? 
Please tag people from Adsense team if you know any.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces the same issue. I fixed it by adding the `<article>` tag to my AMP document.

I believe this happened because we migrated our product to a new one, so Google was caching the HTML of the old one and was serving the Auto-ads based on the old structure of our AMP HTML. 
I hope this help.